# pixel processing in j2me

Tags: image-processing, java-me

I am doing image processing in j2me.I have detected the edge of an image using canny edge detetor.Now i have to select the particular region of an image. Instead of using the  connected component labelling,i want to select the pixel that maximises the pixels of the smoothed image. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JJIL, ("Jon's Java Imaging Library")
http://code.google.com/p/jjil/

> JJIL is a Java image processing library. It includes an image processing architecture and over 60 routines for various image processing tasks.
>
> JJIL is particularly targeted towards mobile applications. It includes interfaces so images can be converted to and from native formats for J2ME, Android, and J2SE.
>
> JJIL includes some sample applications for face detection and EAN-13 (including UPC) barcode reading...